# A question regarding お迎え入れること適わず and 身の上にて陽の下

Tags: grammar, syntax, sentence

> 見れば他にも大勢のお客人がいらっしゃるご様子。貧相な住まいにございましては到底お迎え入れること適わず、本来なればわたくしが門前にてお迎えするが礼儀存じますが、なにぶんひ弱な 身の上にて陽の下はご容赦頂きたく

First is お迎え入れること適わず more or less the same as 迎え入れて適わない?

Second does `なにぶんひ弱な身の上にて陽の下はご容赦頂きたく`means something along the lines :somehow my body\身の上 can not bear benign "under the light"\陽の下 therefor i ask for you pardon ?

Answer (score 1):

(～する)ことかなわず is a stiff set phrase that roughly means the same thing as (～する)ことはできず. This かなう means "(for a wish) to come true". は is omitted in this set phrase probably because it's an old expression.

> 貧相な住まいにございましては到底お迎え入れること適わず、
>   My house is poor, so I can never welcome you into my house, ...

なにぶん used with a reason is a kind of intensifier (perhaps "at any rate" or "after all" is the closest?). [身の上](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%BA%AB%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%8A) by itself refers to one's personal history/circumstances, not one's body. This ～にて is an archaic way of saying ～であって/～でして ("is ～, and/so ..."). Xは容赦してください (or Xは許してください, Xは勘弁してください) literally means "Please be forgiving concerning X". It's used when X is the last thing one wants to do, so it's like "Please, no X!" or "Please, I can do anything but X".

> なにぶんひ弱な身の上にて、陽の下はご容赦頂きたく。
>   (After all,) I have been sickly (for a long time), so please forgive me for not coming under the sun.

Comment: can this 貧相な住まいにございましては  be Literally translated to : if it is ( to) my poor house then ...?

Comment: @lightofgold No, there is actually no "if" there, although even native speakers often make this type of mistake. See ② of [this entry](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF). 順接の確定条件 is a difficult phrase but it refers to a connection like "A, therefore B". This part is 貧相な住まいでございますので in modern Japanese.